# "I need to cook food yet" vs. "I still need to cook food"

Tags: sentence-construction, word-difference

> I need to cook food yet.

vs.

> I still need to cook food.

Is it appropriate to use **yet** at the end of a sentence in that form or should I reform the sentence in a different way to get the same meaning?

Answer (score 1):

"Yet" is always used in the present perfect tense (describing the past up to and including the present). So if you want to use "yet", you would say something like:

> I haven't cooked any food yet.

Your second sentence is correct and sounds normal.

Comment: That's not past tense, that's present perfect.

Comment: Yeah I guess you're right :) I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's exactly grammatically incorrect to use "yet" that way, but it is unidiomatic. "Yet" is usually used in the negative, and since it is discussing what has or hasn't been completed, it's usually used with the perfect aspect. It can also be used to discuss past states: "I hadn't yet cooked food". Confusingly, "yet" can indicate negation with or without "not": "I haven't yet cooked food" and "I haven't cooked food yet" both mean "I haven't cooked food". If we put "yet" in the middle: "I have yet to cook food", then that means "I need to cook food". There's a slight difference in meaning, in that the last one puts more emphasis on needing to do it, while the first two have more of an emphasis on lack of doing it.